# Adding a data based on the specific value of combobox given?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file automated with a macro. I have a userform interface (see photo below). Inside the userform is a combobox and a textbox.

I want to add something in the worksheet but depending on what type of expenses it is and I don't understand what is wrong in my code below. What I want is if I add something in the column of "taxi" (2nd row), I can also in "carwash" (2nd row) but it appears to a different result. I am also not able to add data on 3rd, 4th, 5th rows and so on.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'find first empty row in database

    Set rngNullString = Intersect(ws.Columns("A"), ws.Columns("A")).Find("")
    If rngNullString.row < ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row Then
        Set rngNullString = Intersect(ws.Columns("A"), _
                                      ws.Columns("A")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    End If
    iRow = rngNullString.row

    'check for Name number
    If Trim(Me.TextBox1.value) = "" Then
        Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please complete the FORM"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'copy the data to the database
    If Me.ComboBox1.value = "Taxi" Then
        ws.Cells(iRow, 1).value = Me.ComboBox1.value
        ws.Cells(iRow, 2).value = Me.TextBox1.value
    End If
    If Me.ComboBox1.value = "Carwash" Then
        ws.Cells(iRow, 3).value = Me.ComboBox1.value
        ws.Cells(iRow, 4).value = Me.TextBox1.value
    End If

    MsgBox "Sucessfully! Data added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data Notification"
    'clear the data
    Me.TextBox1.value = ""
    Me.ComboBox1.value = ""
    Me.TextBox1.SetFocus

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please, try `iRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row`

Comment: nothing happen. still the same. the value I added replaced the value in my header

Comment: `iRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1` The previous suggestion returns the last row. Last empty row is the next...

Comment: I already figured out iRow = rngNullString.Row is correct, I forgot to declare the variable of rngNullstring above. Now my problem is how can I add data in the "Carwash" column?

Comment: Very complicated... `ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = "Test"`. Is it possible that this column to not be all the time the third one?